# How to Deploy Blazor PWA App With Rest API (In Virtual Directory) on IIS

Tags: iis, url-rewriting, blazor, blazor-pwa

step 1 - i have a simple blazor pwa app which we hosting in sub domain.
Step 2 - Created new virtual directory
Step 3 - Uploaded APIERP within that virtaul drectory

As blazor is SPA it stops accesss of virtual directory due to routing

i tried to edit web.config in order to rewrite URL
but cant get it to work

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <staticContent>
      <remove fileExtension=".blat" />
      <remove fileExtension=".dat" />
      <remove fileExtension=".dll" />
      <remove fileExtension=".json" />
      <remove fileExtension=".wasm" />
      <remove fileExtension=".woff" />
      <remove fileExtension=".woff2" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".blat" mimeType="application/octet-stream" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".dll" mimeType="application/octet-stream" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".dat" mimeType="application/octet-stream" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".json" mimeType="application/json" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".wasm" mimeType="application/wasm" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff" mimeType="application/font-woff" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff2" mimeType="application/font-woff" />
    </staticContent>
    <httpCompression>
      <dynamicTypes>
        <add mimeType="application/octet-stream" enabled="true" />
        <add mimeType="application/wasm" enabled="true" />
      </dynamicTypes>
    </httpCompression>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="Serve subdir">
          <match url=".*" />
          <action type="Rewrite" url="wwwroot\{R:0}" />
        </rule>
        <rule name="SPA fallback routing" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url=".*" />
          <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="wwwroot\" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

This is default web.config file of blazor
how can add new rule so that it doesnot intercept url for api
e.g mysite.com/apierp/..

Comment: "As blazor is SPA it stops accesss of virtual directory due to routing." I didn't understand clearly what you meant, could you explain this in detail? Under what circumstances will stop accessing the virtual directory?

Answer (score 0):

A Rewrite action replaces the current URL string with a substitution string. A substitution string must always specify the URL path (for example, contoso/test/default.aspx). Note that substitutions that contain a physical path on a file system (for example, C:\inetpub\wwwroot) are not supported in IIS.

For how to create rewrite rules for URL rewrite module, you can refer to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/creating-rewrite-rules-for-the-url-rewrite-module). You can also read the [URL Rewrite Module Configuration Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/url-rewrite-module-configuration-reference).

In addition, when you get the error while using the URL rewrite module, you can use [Failed Request Tracing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules) to trace rewrite rules.